# Using a dynamic variable as object literal, jQuery animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Originally I had

```
targetWater.animate({
    "width": "+=100%"
```

Now I want to dynamically use "width" or "height"

```
var direction = (targetWater.hasClass('x'))? "width" : "height";
targetWater.animate({
    direction: "+=100%"
```

But this doesn't work.

I've tried

```
direction.toString()
```

and

```
''+direction+''
```

No joy with this either

```
var anim = { direction: "+=100%" }
targetWater.animate(anim,
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work since `direction` is interpreted as a key, not a variable.

You can do it like so:

```
var animation = {};
var direction = targetWater.hasClass('x') ? "width" : "height"
animation[direction] = "+=100%";
targetWater.animate(animation);
```

The square brackets make it so you *can* have the key dynamically.

---

If you would want the key `"direction"` with the square bracket notation you would write:

```
animation["direction"];
```

which is equivalent to:

```
animation.direction;
```

Comment: +1, all answers are correct, this one is well formatted and explained.

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket notation:

```
var anim = {};
anim[direction] = "+=100%";
```

Answer (score 2):

You variable does not get interpolated, you need to define it the following way:

```
var options = {};
options[direction] = "+=100%";

targetWater.animate( options , /*...*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create it as a property and pass it to the `.animate` function. See below,

```
var direction = (targetWater.hasClass('x'))? "width" : "height";

var animProp = {};
animProp[direction] = "+=100%";

targetWater.animate(animProp, /*..*/);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use "Array-like" (bracket) notation to create the "right"/dynamic property:

```
var animation = {};
animation[targetWater.hasClass('x'))? "width" : "height"] = "+=100%";

targetWater.animate(animation);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use variables inside keys. Either you build the object with bracket notation

```
var anim = {};
anim[ targetWater.hasClass('x') ? "width" : "height" ] = "+=100%";
targetWater.animate(anim, …
```

or you don't use an object

```
targetWater.animate(targetWater.hasClass('x') ? "width" : "height", "+=100%", …
```