# How can I pass function arguments to jquery .animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a dynamic variable as object literal, jQuery animate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236473/using-a-dynamic-variable-as-object-literal-jquery-animate-function)

I'm attempting to pass a function argument as a setting for a jquery animation except I cannot get it working.

The Function

```
function gridClick(a, b){
    $(c).animate({
        a : 0,
        b : 0
    }, 10000)
};
```

calling the function

```
gridClick('top', 'left', this);
```

console log shows that a and b are being put out as top and left but they are not actually affecting the animation as top and left. Is this a syntax error or is there more going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a dynamic variable as object literal, jQuery animate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236473/using-a-dynamic-variable-as-object-literal-jquery-animate-function) and [Setting object keys from variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864544/setting-object-keys-from-variables).

Comment: Is `c` meant to be a third argument to the function?

Comment: yes but c is unrelated to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use a variable name as an object's property name using object literal. Here is one possible workaround:

```
function gridClick(a, b) {
    var params = {};
    params[a] = 0;
    params[b] = 0;
    $(c).animate(params, 10000);
};
```

Comment: OP is missing the 3rd arg (c) and you are missing it too :)

Comment: `c` could be global, could be defined in the outer scope, etc.

Comment: I am doubting that because of `gridClick('top', 'left', this);`.. but what you said may be true.. btw I didn't dw your answer as that is not at all related to the question.

Comment: that worked. any way I can add other attributes to animation? such as .animate(params{height: 100}, 1000)?

Comment: For consistency with the lines that set `a` and `b`, you can add `params["height"] = 100;` -- or -- `params.height = 100;`. Another is to initialize the object like `var params = {height: 100};`

Comment: ok i got it working. thanks Salman!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables for property names, you will need to use bracket notation and assignments. The literal syntax does not support it.

Instead, use:

```
function gridClick(a, b, c) {
    var opts = {};
    opts[a] = 0;
    opts[b] = 0;
    $(c).animate(opts, 10000)
}
```

Comment: Hmm where did `params` come from :)